# Accelerated Mobile Pages for job postings

Tags: seo, amp

We are currently rebuilding our website I am researching advantages of Accelerated Mobile Pages. We are offering a lot content like job postings with some basic interaction (like 'apply' button that redirects the user to job application form). Our marketing department is using Facebook and other social media as one of it's main channels. Since AMP is compatible with Facebook Instant Articles and gives SEO boost, are there any disadvantages of using RWD website + AMP pages for certain type of content?

Does this type of content (job postings with some basic interaction) collide in any way with the idea of AMP and may affect our user experience and SEO negatively?

Answer (score 2):

The AMP spec was created to ensure that pages are lightweight, load very quickly, and are easy to parse. As such, the benefit for SEO lies in the page speed factor: the faster you page loads, the more search engines like it. If your AMP pages are loading faster than your regular pages, you may see some SERP benefits. However, if you regular pages are the same speed as your AMP pages, you may see no change in rankings. I recommend testing to see if there's a difference, since job posting pages are generally pretty lightweight to begin with.

Originally, AMP pages were limited to the Google News carousel, but given the adoption rate and the performance boost, other content is also starting to benefit from AMP and appear in carousels and such. However, this is not yet the case for every type of content; I haven't seen any impact on the job posting category in the wild. But that doesn't mean there won't be impact in the future. 
Thus, you should not be negatively affected, SEO-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing AMP on a job posting site would not negatively impact it SEO-wise, and it would be beneficial in terms of fast access through Google's search engine. For example, I found that websites in India have already implemented AMP on job postings.